# Gatling - Pause inside of loop

Tags: java, scala, gatling, bzt

I'm trying to use a pause inside of a loop with gatling and after a single run I would expect the loop to only execute ~3 times but it's executing about 1/sec.

I'm using bzt as the runner with:

```
hold-for: 30s
concurrency: 1
iterations: 1
throughput: 1
```

```
private val scn = scenario("Post, Poll, and Delete")
      .forever {
          exec(http("Post").post(url + path)
            .check(status.is(201))
            .check(jsonPath("$..id").saveAs("id"))
          )
            .doWhile(session => session("status").as[String] == "STARTED", "index") {
              pause(10.seconds)
              exec(http("Poll")
                .get(url + path)
                .queryParam(id, session => session("id").as[String])
                .check(jsonPath("$..status").saveAs("status"))
                .check(jsonPath("$..status").not("ERROR"))
              )
          }.exec(http("Delete")
                  .delete(url + path)
                  .check(status.is(200))
            )
      }
```

Edit: With help from [Stéphane] I used the below:

```
.doWhile(condition) {
  pace(???)
  .exec(???)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, the result of the last operation is what the block returns.
So what you've written is basically:

```scala
.doWhile(condition) {
  pause(???)

  return exec(???)
}
```

You can see the problem: what's passed as `doWhile` second parameter is only the `exec` without the preceding `pause`.

This happens because you've forgotten to attach them with a dot.

So what you have to do is:

```scala
.doWhile(condition) {
  pause(???)
  .exec(???)
}
```

I also see that you're using a third party launcher (sad). Not sure what it does, in particular `throughput: 1` whose wording doesn't match anything in Gatling. If it actually sets up [`throttling`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/simulation_setup/#throttling), this disables pauses, as explained in the documentation.

Comment: Interesting I had just assumed everything was synchronous, thank you!

Unfortunately, the above did not work. Requests were still being sent with seemingly no pause.

I instead used [pace](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/general/scenario/#pace) which behaved as expected and from the documentation seems to be identical.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think the way you've set up your third party launcher disables the pauses.

Comment: I’ll bet you’re right actually. I have no clue what bzt is doing behind the scenes there with Gatling.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

`pace(duration)`

to pause inside the loop

and use

`pause(duration)`

outside the loop

check [this](https://octoperf.com/blog/2020/05/07/kraken-gatling-loops-conditions-pauses-think-times/#pacing)